# How to change UICollectionView zIndex?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, tvos

Check the image below. I need to **highlight** the focused cell such that it is above all the cells in `collectionView`.
I know I have to change the `zIndex` of the focused cell. How to do that?
I need the logic. My code is in `objective-c`.

This is for `tvOS` but `iOS` code will also work here I guess.

[image]

Comment: Do you have Sample code for this?

Comment: I don't have. If I remember correctly, You just have to change the `zPosition` of your nextfocused cell's layer to one inside the `didUpdateFocusInContext:` method. Also set the previouslyFocused cell's zPosition to zero. It should work.

Comment: Is this a UICollectionViewCell's method? If so I have added it, but not getting  called. Do any more settings required.

Comment: `didUpdateFocusInContext` is a tvOS method. Are you working on tvOS?

Comment: ohh..I am working on iOS.

Comment: Changing the zPosition should work on iOS as well. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683878/ios-uicollectionviewcells-layout-with-intersection

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried setting value for `cell.layer.zPosition`?

Comment: This will work .But we should manually set the previous cell's layers's zPosition to zero and current active cell's layers's zPosition to one.

Answer (score 9):

Try manually applying `layer.zPosition` to be the `zIndex` in `applyLayoutAttributes:` method of `UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    [super applyLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
    self.layer.zPosition = layoutAttributes.zIndex;
}
```

Comment: how to get current selected index in this method

Comment: @RohitPradhan there's no easy way to get selected index, but you can use self.isSelected to check whether current cell selected or not

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a custom collection view flow layout. Compute the zIndex based on the collection view's scroll position or visible rect. The sample class is shown below.

```
final class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        attributes?.forEach {
            $0.zIndex = 0 //Compute and set
        }
        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attribute = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        attribute?.zIndex = 0 //Compute and set
        return attribute
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set the z-position of collection view to -2, unhighlight to -1 and highlight to 0